# Handling keyboard and blur/focus events in a backbone js app

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am building a app using backbonejs and marionette and need some inputs on how to change the focus of fields based on keys and detecting blur/focusout of "div" or "li" tags.

http://jsbin.com/akiyiw/18/edit

The above jsbin link shows what I have now and am trying to achieve the following.

1. On typing the "enter" key in the title field the focus should move to the "fullname" field of the very first row.
2. Similarly on typing the "enter" key anywhere( fullname text field or other elements like "p" etc..) in the firstrow(GridRow view) the focus should move to the next row and so on.
3. Also would like to detect the focus exiting out for the row ( GridRow view) to trigger an automatic save. The exit can be due to the "enter" key or due to clicking of the mouse outside the row.

For #1 and #2 I have been trying with keydown events but not sure how to move the focus from one view to another.

For #3 I tried using the blur and focusout events but not very successful.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using marionete you can use event aggregator
and trigger events on the other views.
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone-eventbinder/

In this blog post Derick explains it better that I would.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I use marionette and your suggestion is one of the options. My app already has a lot of events and was looking if there is a solution without having to use a bunch of new events. But looks like that may be the only option. Thanks for your answer.